# Double integral $\int\!\!\int_S x^2 dydz - 2y^2 dzdx + 3z^2 dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate the surface integral of the second kind:
$$
\int\!\!\int_S x^2 dydz - 2y^2 dzdx + 3z^2 dxdy.
$$
The boundary of integrals $S$ is the outer side of the surface of the parallelepiped $[0,1] × [0,1] × [0,1]$.

I've got an answer $1/3$ using vectors but I'm not sure

Comment: @Gary no its double integral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's recall the divergence theorem. If we have a $V\subset \mathbb{R}^3$  compact and with a piecewise smooth boundary, $\partial V=S$, and we have a vector field $F:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $F\in C^1(A)$, where $A$ is an open set containing $V$, the following formula holds: $\iint_{\partial V}\langle F,n\rangle dS=\iiint_V\operatorname{div}Fdxdydz$. Our vector field is $F(x,y,z)=(x^2,-2y^2,3z^2)$ so $\operatorname{div}F=F^{1}_{x}+F^{2}_{y}+F^{3}_{z}=2x-4y+6z$. That means $\iint_{S}\langle F,n\rangle dS=\iiint_{V}(2x-4y+6z)dxdydz=\int_{0}^{1}dx\int_{0}^{1}dy\int_{0}^{1}(2x-4y+6z)dz$. With iterated integration I obtained the result $\iint_{\partial V}\langle F,n\rangle dS=2$.

Comment: Use \langle and \rangle to get $\langle$ and $\rangle$. Use \mathbb{R} to get $\mathbb{R}$. Use \operatorname{div} to get $\operatorname{div}$.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the answer to modify these notations.